# ModuleNotFound: No module named 'linclass'

Tags: python, modulenotfounderror

I am trying to import linclass on colab jupyter notebook. But I am having a ModuleNotFound error, and I do not know how to install linclass. I tried to run !pip install linclass but it didn't work.

I tried

```
!pip install linclass
from linclass import linclass
```

Comment: Which `linclass` module are you talking about?

Comment: What happened when you tried to run `!pip install linclass`?

Comment: There's no module named 'linclass' available at PyPI, as you can see for yourself when searching for it there. If you had gone there & filled it in the search form, you'd see [this](https://pypi.org/search/?q=linclass). Thus, the attempt you wrote won't work because it is meant for packages indexed there. Always link or describe the resource you are trying to use if it is an non-standard package. (You can distinguish with the test I just described.) Whatever you are attempting to do probably tells you or assumes you know to copy a file that has linclass defined into current working directory.

Comment: Thank you for your response. You are right! I was trying to solve a SVM problem, but did not understand that the instructor had given a non-standard package. The file was named 'linclass.py.' I did not see it first and tried to run the code. Hence, the problem occurred.